# How to Container.Update , Container.Refresh?

Tags: xbmc, kodi

In my Kodi plugin I build a container with list items:

```
elif methode == 'get_item_serienplaner':
sp_items = refreshWidget(__LS__(30116))
url = '-'
for sitem in sp_items:

    li = xbmcgui.ListItem(label2=sitem['TVShow'], label=sitem['Title'], thumbnailImage=sitem['Thumb'])
    li.setProperty("channel", sitem['Channel'])
    li.setArt({'poster': sitem['Poster']})
    li.setProperty("plot", sitem['Description'])
    li.setProperty("staffel", sitem['Staffel'])
    li.setProperty("episode", sitem['Episode'])
    li.setProperty("starttime", sitem['Starttime'])
    li.setProperty("rating", sitem['Rating'])
    li.setProperty("senderlogo", sitem['Logo'])
    li.setProperty("genre", sitem['Genre'])
    li.setProperty("date", sitem['Datum'])
    li.setProperty("runtime", sitem['RunningTime'])
    li.setProperty("studio", sitem['Studio'])
    li.setProperty("year", sitem['Jahr'])
    li.setProperty("altersfreigabe", sitem['Altersfreigabe'])
    li.setProperty("status", sitem['Status'])
    li.setProperty("label", sitem['Title'])
    li.setProperty("label2", sitem['TVShow'])
    xbmcplugin.addDirectoryItem(handle=addon_handle, url=url, listitem=li)
xbmcplugin.endOfDirectory(addon_handle)
```

So the container is called from the skin as follows:

```
<content>plugin://plugin.program.serienplaner/?methode=get_item_serienplaner</content>
```

Now I have the problem that `refreshWidget(__LS__(30116))` will be updated every 5min but how can I update the container with the ListItems for Kodi so that this will be updated to?

I tried with `Container.Update()` and `Container.Refresh` but it did not work.